# Execute procedure using synonym over DB link

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, dblink

I have a problem with executing procedure over the DB link

I have three databases:

DB1, DB2, and DB3

- DB1 is the source database where is the procedure
- DB2 is the "gateway" database
- DB3 is the database from which procedure from DB1 is executing over the db link from DB2

DB1:

```
create user DB1EXECUTOR identified by "password";
grant connect, create session to DB1EXECUTOR;
grant execute on DB1SOURCE.PROCEDURE1 to DB1EXECUTOR;
```

DB2:

```
create user DB3_TO_DB1_CONNECTOR identified by "password";
grant connect, create session, create synonym, create database link to DB3_TO_DB1_CONNECTOR;

=====using DB3_TO_DB1_CONNECTOR user:=====
create database link DB2_TO_DB1_DBLINK connect to DB1EXECUTOR identified by "password" using 'DB1';
create synonym PROCEDURE1 for PROCEDURE1@DB2_TO_DB1_DBLINK;
```

DB3:

```
create user DB3APP identified by "password";
grant connect, create session, create synonym, create database link to DB3APP;

=====using DB3APP user:=====
create database link DB3_TO_DB2_DBLINK connect to DB3_TO_DB1_CONNECTOR identified by "password" using 'DB2';
create synonym PROCEDURE1 for PROCEDURE1@DB3_TO_DB2_DBLINK;
```

Finally, when I try to execute PROCEDURE1 from DB1 over db link from DB2, then everything is good:

```
=====using DB2 database and DB3_TO_DB1_CONNECTOR user:=====
execute PROCEDURE1

ok
```

but when I try to execute this same procedure over db link from DB3, then this not working...

```
=====using DB3 database and DB3APP user:=====
execute PROCEDURE1

...
PLS-00352: Unable access to another database "DB2_TO_DB1_DBLINK"
...
PLS-00201: identifier "PROCEDURE1" must be declared
...
```

What's wrong here?
I don't understant why I can execute PROCEDURE1 from DB2 but not from DB3...

Comment: Which database versions are those DB1, DB2 and DB3?

Comment: DB1 (Source): EE 12.2.0.1,
DB2 ("Gateway"): SO 11.2.0.3,
DB3 ("App"): EE 12.2.0.1.

 DB1 and DB3 environments will be upgraded to 19c in the near future.

 The DB2 environment was not updated because it serves us only as a "gateway" where only network traffic passes through it and it does not contain any data.
In short, we provide there selected synonyms, views, etc. by which that the application databases do not have direct contact with the source databases (security reasons).

 Do you think the difference in database versions could be the problem here?

Comment: I thought the difference *might* be a problem. It sometimes is, when the difference is "too high" (for example, a DB link from 12c to 10g where 10g should be at least 10.2.0.2). Your versions seem to be *close enough*, so - no, I think that's not the issue here. Is the procedure **overloaded**? MOS says that this might be a problem.

Comment: I prepared a fresh lab environment with three databases in the same version (12.2.0.1).
Unfortunately, the problem occurs here as well, so it seems that the version of the database is not the cause.
For testing I used this very simple procedure "CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE greetings AS BEGIN dbms_output.put_line('Hello World!'); END; /"
Works from a database that is directly connected to it.
It looks like something can't execute a procedure that goes through two databases via dblinks
This is really a puzzling problem

Comment: I used that "intermediate" database when it was impossible to create direct database link between two very different database versions, but - I had synonyms to tables only, not procedures so I can't tell what's wrong (based on my own experience). If it still doesn't work (even though all 3 databases share the same version), huh ... no idea, sorry.